# Download Binary data file from java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server

Hi Here my Sql Table[image]

I want to download those files using java script . I get Record from "ID" to my java script . I want to download those files, how can i do that
here is the my script get file by ID

```
function DownloadFile(e) {



    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/api/FileAttachment/GetFileByID',
        async: false,
        data: { id: e },
        success: function (data) {


            downloadPDFfile(data);




        }
    });

}

  function downloadPDFfile(a) {

   // I want write download code here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a file from server, at first create a url request like this:

```
function downloadPDFfile(param) {
    var downloadUrl = http://www.yourhost.com/download?id=param
    window.open(downloadUrl);
}
```

At your server, write code to receive this request, get requested param(s), read your binary data from db then response this data to client as a stream and the browser will do it's job.

Dont't forget to specify HTTP **response** header fields. For example:

```
Content-Type: text/html /* MIME type */
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext" /* Using 'attachment' option to raise a "File Download" dialogue box */
```